# ¿Porqué no puedo utilizar la función fa() cuando pongo cor ya sea pearson, poly o tetra?

Tags: r

Estoy haciendo un análisis factorial exploratorio con `fa()`, sin embargo cuando pongo `cor()` ya sea policórico, tetracórico o pearson obtengo ese error, ¿qué puedo hacer?

> factor<-fa(AMMSA_resultados,nfactors = 1,fm = "ml",rotate ="varimax",
> cor = "poly")
>
> **Error in if (any(lower > upper)) stop("lower>upper integration limits") : valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario Además: Warning
> messages:
>
> 1: In polychoric(x, weight = weight, global = global) : The items do
> not have an equal number of response alternatives, global set to
> FALSE.
>
> 2: In qnorm(cumsum(rsum)[-length(rsum)]) : NaNs produced**

[Datos para el análisis](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cvRhVBV2W9Qh5j8rMMHpIEab7x-2O26W7RLL5tF7824/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos Puma a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿Cómo contruyes `AMMSA_resultados` a partir de los datos que compartiste? ¿Podrías agregar ese código así tu pregunta queda reproducible?

Comment: buenas, exactamente AMMSA_resultados es la base de datos del excel

Comment: Supongo que estás usando `psych::fa()`. Es bastante delicada con los imput, sobre todo para crear las matrices de correlación policóricas o tetracóricas: no acepta que les pases factores. Además es legendaria por lo poco informativos que son sus errores. Será muy difícil ayudarte si no compartes un ejemplo de los datos. Si por cuestiones de privacidad o anonimato no puedes compartirlos podrías incluir otros que tengan exactamente la misma estructura, sobre las clases a las que pertenece cada columna.